# asp net custom errors defaultRedirect changing case

Tags: asp.net, case-sensitive, custom-error-pages

on an ASP Net 3.5 web app I have defaultRedirect="Views/Shared/Error.aspx". The name of my web site is "XXX".

For some reason, when an error is detected, the error page searched is "https://www.xxx.com/Views/Shared/Error.aspx" and it throws an error, because my page is behind a reverse proxy which is case sensitive. It is, the call to the error page should be "https://www.XXX.com/Views/Shared/Error.aspx"

Is there a way to specify to ASP net that the call should be case sensitive???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were having a similar problem with our .Net site running behind a reverse proxy server (that was case sensitive). The fix turned out to be adding a leading "~/" to the setting.

So in your case, that would be:

`defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying your proxy is case-sensitive as to the *domain* name?

There is no way to enable case-sensitivity for the domain name in ASP.NET as domain names are not supposed to be case sensitive.

It might be possible to build a kludge for this because a redirect is simply a Location header and a status code 301. However, it's not a setting that you enable. You'd have to build your own error handling script.